# Asp.NET MVC 4 Ajax ActionLink help needed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have an Ajax ActionLink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Science Package", "GetScience", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "ShowData" })
```

The whole idea being the fact that, onclicking the link, it would fetch all data from the GetScience method ( which returns a List of objects) and displays it in a div. The question is how to do that?
I am trying using the OnSuccess method, to catch the results, loop over the values and display them in the view. But it doesn't seem to work. Please help?

Comment: did you add the **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** script in header?

Comment: MVC4 needs adding : @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") and this suffices the work. I tried with returning a single string from the method & t worked perfectly. The problem happens with a list of objects getting returned.

Comment: Can you share your JSON data which returned by GetScience action method?

Comment: For the list of objects, the return type from the Action is a custom object type, not a JSON. Please let me know if that's wrong.

Comment: Share your controller's action

Comment: public IEnumerable<Course> GetScience(){ var courseModel _db.Courses.ToList();

            //return Json(courseModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return courseModel;
        }

Comment: The method you posted is not an action result, it must be an action result so it can be accessible via anchor.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan: just debugged that, inside the JS function showData where i was catching the response, this line 'var response = ajaxContent.get_response;' is not working, coz there seems no propert for get_response, neither get_response(), neither get_response.get_object()

Comment: Have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@soumadeep as per the discussion I believe the date retrieval technique in your case must be like below

**Controller :**

```
public JsonResult GetScience() 
{ 
    var courseModel _db.Courses.ToList(); 
    return Json(courseModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

**View JS:**

```
function ShowData(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Did successfully by returning JsonResult, my question was is it not possible by returning List of objects the way i did?

Comment: @soumadeep, no because there should be a URL form which anchor can get the data.

Comment: okk...thanks a lot, just one last query..i beleive it is possible to prevent the json popup to save the json data from popping up my screen everytime i click the link :P

Comment: json popup what does it mean?

Comment: a dialog box opens i IE where an option is given to open, cancel or download the json

Answer (score 0):

```
Just to update everything in a nutshell, after grilling for a lot of time & @kundan's suggestions did what i wanted to acheive. The details are below:

**The link:** 

     @Ajax.ActionLink("Science Package", "GetScience", new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess = "UpdateData" })

**The Action:**     

public JsonResult GetScience()
    {
        var courseModel = _db.Courses.ToList();
       // return "";
        return Json(courseModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

**The JS:** 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function UpdateData(data) {
            var target = $("#Context");
            target.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var product = data[i];
                target.append("<ul><b><ul>" + product.Name + "</ul></b><ul>" + product.Description + "</ul><b><ul>" + product.FacultyName + "</ul></b><ul>" + product.Price+ "</ul></ul>");
            }
        }
    </script>


**The JS includes in layout file:** 

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

The above steps will help you make async calls to Action methods & return results on the same page/ partial views. 
Question, let me know by mail. Will be more than happy to get grilled :)
```